# How to avoid to Reference a Java object multiple times

Tags: java, reference, pass-by-reference

In some way I'm trying to avoid multiple reference to an specific object. I have the following:

```
public class A
{
   private C c;
  
   public A()
   {
      this.c = new C();
   }

   public C getC()
   {
       return this.c;
   }
}
```

Then I have:

```
public class B extends A
{
   private C c;

   public B()
   {
       super();
   }

   public void someMethod()
   {
       // I want to avoid this
       this.c = getC();
     
       // But I want to allow the execution of methods inside C
       getC().someMethodOfC();
   }
}
```

I guess that in C++ it could be done with some operator overloading but I've seen that in Java this is not possible.

Is there any way to only have one reference of the object in Java (And don't allow the creation of more references)

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid multiple reference to an specific object" Why?

Comment: What's your problem here? Are you worried about creating multiple instances of a Class?

Comment: There is a way to have only one reference to an object. But you should consider carefully if that's actually what you want/need, or if you should keep the multiple references. If you are sure you want to do this, look into singletons.

Comment: @AndyTurner We are giving our code to another Team and we don't want to allow this

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper it's not a singleton what I want to do, the think is that I want to create object C each time A is created an that the only reference that have to exist to this object have to be the one stored as private in C class with a singleton I'll only have one C object for all other objects

Comment: What good does it do to have only a single reference? Why not allow multiple references?

Comment: @david.t_92 Well, that's hardly "only have one reference of the object" and "don't allow the creation of more references". You'd have one per instance of A, which is a different thing entirely.

Comment: So, just remove the `private C c;` field and the `this.c = getC();` statement from `B` and call `getC().someMethodOfC();` as intended. Where’s the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question fully. You may make C a private inner class in A, expose a method in A that uses C to perform the operations/actions that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `private C c;` in `class B`. By extending `B` from `A`, you have access on `public` and `protected` members of `A`. This includes `public C getC()` of class `A`. If you want direct access on member `c` of `A` in `B`, make `c` `protected`.